# select ng-options not updating ng-model in AngularJS with ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, autocomplete

I have a simple question and I really dont know what am I missing in my logic.

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwno55hj/101/) is working fine (not using ajax/timeout) but I want to understand and also fix why the following behavior is not happening when I apply the same logic with a timeout/ajax !!

Here is my simple sample: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yyk2gL49/4/)

HTML:

```
<body data-ng-app="appMain">
    <div ng-controller="SearchController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="SearchTerm" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit Search" ng-click="QuerySuggestions()" />
        <select ng-show="ShowSuggestion" name="cmbSelectedSuggestion" ng-model="SelectedSuggestion" ng-options="text as suggestion.Detail for suggestion in SuggestionList" ng-change="WhoIsSelected(suggestion)">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('appMain',[])
.controller('SearchController',function($scope, $http, $timeout){
  $scope.SearchTerm = '';
  $scope.ShowSuggestion = false;
  $scope.SuggestionList = [];
  $scope.SelectedSuggestion = null;
  $scope.QuerySuggestions = function()
  {
    //Simulating an AJAX that my response happens 2s afterwards
    $timeout(function(){
      var oJSON = {"List": [
              {
                  "Id": 1,
                  "Type": "State",
                  "Name": "Rio de Janeiro",
                  "Detail": "Rio de Janeiro - State, Brazil"
              }
              ,
              {
                  "Id": 1,
                  "Type": "City",
                  "Name": "Rio de Janeiro",
                  "Detail": "Rio de Janeiro - City, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"
              }]};

        $scope.SuggestionList = oJSON.List
        $scope.ShowSuggestion = true;
    }, 2000);

  }

  $scope.WhoIsSelected = function($option){
    $scope.WhoIsSelectedFirstApproach();
    $scope.WhoIsSelectedSecondApproach($option);
  }

  $scope.WhoIsSelectedFirstApproach = function(){
    console.log($scope.SelectedSuggestion); //why undefined !?!?!
  }

  $scope.WhoIsSelectedSecondApproach = function($option){
    console.log($option) //why undefined ?!?!?
  }
})
```

Comment: First of all I think you should be using $timeout service

Comment: Sure, that would avoid the necessity to do #scope.$apply, gona update the problem script

Answer (score 1):

In your ng-options, it should be `suggestion.Detail as text` instead of `text as suggestion.Detail`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bigger search I manage to solve and also understand my mistakes.

First, Due to my T-SQL background I was unterstanding that "text" was an alias for sugestion.Detail field in the expression `text as suggestion.Detail for suggestion in SuggestionList` but thats not the case! 
The word "text" here is not an ALIAS it is the object/object.field that u want AngularJS do expose as the ng-model... so, that said, the solution in my case (object in the list as ng-model) was updating to: `suggestion as suggestion.Detail for suggestion in SuggestionList`

```
ng-options="suggestion as suggestion.Detail for suggestion in SuggestionList"
```

Ok that simply resolves the WhoIsSelectedFirstApproach, but if I want to pass the object to a function in the ng-change, using `suggestion` in the expression doenst work... (dont know why they used different expression logics for different ng-*) but to solve that problem figured that u can reference the ng-model field inside the ng-change: so I could manage that changing `Function(suggestion)` to `Function(modelField)` as follows:

```
ng-change="WhoIsSelected(SelectedSuggestion)"
```

[SOLVED JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yyk2gL49/7/)